# Is it reasonable to like Contract Law, but find Commercial Law too abstruse and impractical?

Tags: discussion

How can [Is it reasonable to like Contract Law, but find Commercial Law too abstruse and impractical?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/67132/38612) be saved or revised to become on topic? I know that it's opinion-based, but I would appreciate advice on this question. xngtng's comments assist.

Comment: No, this question inherently requires either offering the personal opinion of the answerer or seeking to justify or negate the opinion in the question. Some things cannot be turned into logic. Whether one would, should, could or does like a particular subfield or not is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

**Is it reasonable to like opera but not like football?**

Personal taste is personal taste. The question will always be opinion based.